# Table Per Hierarchy & Inherited Relationships

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties, table-per-hierarchy

I'm using Entity Framework 5, targeting .Net 4.5. For the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong that's causing the following error while trying to work with Table Per Hierarchy and Navigation columns:

> Invalid column name 'Game_Category'.
>   Invalid column name 'Game_Value'.
>   Invalid column name 'Type_Category'.
>   Invalid column name 'Type_Value'.

Here's the abstract base class (note the composite PK on Category and Value):

```
[Table("Dictionary")]
public abstract class Lookup
{
  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  [StringLength(50)]
  public string Category { get; set; }

  [StringLength(100)]
  public string ExtendedValue { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(50)]
  public string Key { get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Followed by two subclasses that add no additional columns...

```
public class Game : Lookup {}

public class SetType : Lookup {}
```

Here's the class with Navigation properties to Game and SetType...

```
public class CardSet
{
  [Required]
  [StringLength(10)]
  public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

  public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int GameId { get; set; }

  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(100)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

  public virtual Lookup Type { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int TypeId { get; set; }
}
```

From my data context...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Lookup>()
    .Map<Game>(l => l.Requires("LookupType").HasValue("Game"))
    .Map<SetType>(l => l.Requires("LookupType").HasValue("Set Type"));

  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The lookup table has a discriminator column named LookupType. I've read through several tutorials on table/inheritance. The other two - TPT and TPC using similarly built objects were a cinch. While I understand the errors above - that it's looking for FK columns by convention, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or missing that's causing it to look for those columns. I've tried placing ForeignKey attributes over the GameId and TypeId properties, but then I get errors about dependent/principal relationship constraints and I'm not sure how to specify the category as an additional foreign key.

I have yet to find a tutorial on table/inheritance that goes over navigation properties as I'm using them. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been driving me nuts for over an hour.

**Update:**

I believe the problem lies in the use of Category as part of the key. The CardSet doesn't have two properties for the category of "Game" for that lookup or the category for "Set Type" for that lookup. I tried creating these properties but that didn't work. Is it possible to set those using the Fluent API? I've made about a dozen attempts so far without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that EF does not "like" the construct `modelBuilder.Entity<Lookup>()` to map the two sub classes. This should help:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
  .Map(l => l.Requires("LookupType").HasValue("Game"));
modelBuilder.Entity<SetType>()
  .Map(l => l.Requires("LookupType").HasValue("Set Type"));
```

Comment: I was really hoping it'd be that simple. Your suggestion throws me a different set of validation errors:  
  
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:  

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.  
  
But the tutorial [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) which show the Entity using the base class.

Comment: You're right! So I tried your model and didn't get any error. The code as given works (EF 5, VS2012, .Net4.5). I only have a `DbSet<Lookup>` and a `DbSet<CardSet>` in my context. Are there any other classes that you left out for simplicity? BTW I'll remove this answer, or edit it if we make any progress on this.

Comment: I have a separate project with the full model, but even my simpler project with just the above model does not work when I do this:  
  
_dataContext.Dictionary.Where(l => l.Category == categoryName && l.IsActive == activeOnly);

categoryName = "Game" and activeOnly = true

Comment: Yeah no luck for me. I tried a workaround to remove Category from being a Key and set it to required, but that didn't work on my larger model.